# How do I keep cells aligned together with the table?

Tags: css, width, css-tables, cells

[image: Table]

I know that this could have an easy solution, but I tried everything and I couldn't make it work.

If I size down my page its all perfectly symmetric, but when I size up to fullscreen it happens like in the photo.

What I want it to do is to let the cells keep the size of the table, and not just showing the background.

The main problem is in a particular cell that contains a certain text, which is longer in certain ones than in others.

I've already tried to make a specific width, but if I do that I can't have a dynamic cell while I size down the browser.

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: Sorry, here it is: http://pastebin.com/4HABdEAV     
I did nothing special to it, just i can't make it work properly.
Here's also a more specific image, where they aren't symmetrical: http://imgur.com/y3KnTgf

Comment: @MatthewSeph Use https://jsfiddle.net/ for the code and if you give some code try to give CSS and HTML 1st for that we have everything we need to work and 2nd for that we see what you tried alredy

Comment: ...and the HTML...!? Are you sure you're not opening a new table for each row?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not much prepared, its my first post here. Anyway, here there's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/36k3Lr85/ 
I think that everything is on the same <table>, feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken.
This is a project where I've got 2 more html pages, but those are not linked to the problem, the main problem is only with the css and the table. Thanks to both for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  border: 16px blue solid;
}
td {
  border: 8px lime solid;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 44px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</td>
    <td>adipisci</td>
    <td>velit</td>
    <td>quisquam</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did that part.
My problem is when i create more than one <tr>, and they aren't symmetrical.
Here's a more specific image: http://imgur.com/y3KnTgf
And here's the .css code: http://pastebin.com/4HABdEAV